# CW complex which is a union of contractible subcomplexes with contractible intersection is contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Im trying to show that if X is a CW complex, A,B $\subset $X are contractible sub complexes with contractible intersection and $X=A\cup B$, then X is contractible.

We can say that X/A$\cap$B is homotopy equivalent to X since (X,A$\cap$B) satisfies the homotopy extension property and $A\cap B$ is contractible. Now we have $A/A\cap B \cup B/A\cap B=X/A\cap B$ and as before $A/A\cap B$ and $B/A\cap B$ are homotopy equivalent to $A$ and $B$ respectively which are contractible. In general we can't say that if $A\simeq X$, $B \simeq Y$ then $A\cup B \simeq X\cup Y$ and even if it was true we could have that $A$ and $B$ are homotopy equivalent to different points.

Are there mistakes so far ? Any idea on how to proceed if not ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: One way to establish this is to use the Seifert van Kampen, Hurewicz, and Mayer-Vietoris theorems together with the fact that a weakly contractible CW complex is contractible. However, there may be a more direct proof along the lines you propose.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Mayer-Vietoris requires interiors of subspaces to cover whole $X$. With this additional assumption, yes, it is true. Without it? I'm not so sure. Plus for what you need Seifert van Kampen or Hurewicz here?

Comment: @freakish: I forgot about that assumption, you're right. If you only use Mayer-Vietoris, you can only conclude $X$ has trivial homology, which is not enough to deduce that it is contractible.

Comment: Certainly you want to have $X  = A \cup B$.

Comment: I think, we can show that, $\pi_n(X)=0\forall n$ and $X$ being a cw complex , it will imply that $X$ is contractible. To achieve this goal, take a map $f:S^n\to X$ as image of $f$ is compact, assume that X has finitely many cells, next if image of $f$ is contained in one of $A,B$ ,we are thorough, if not, the image of $f$ contains in both $A,B$ then deform those cells of $B$ to its boundary in which image of $f$ intersects, and now image of $f$ lies completely in $A$ and again we are through. Correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @freakish Van Kampen and Mayer-Vietoris are both true using subcomplexes of CW complexes: for every subcomplex $A$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $A$ which deformation retracts to $A$; and for every pair of subcomplexes $A,B$ there are neighborhoods $U,V$ such that $U$ deformation retracts to $A$, $V$ deformation retracts to $B$, and $U \cap V$ deformation retracts to $A \cap B$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget to mention that $X = A \cup B$, otherwise it is not true.

You correctly state that if $(Z,C)$ has the homotopy extension property and $C$ is contractible, then $Z \simeq Z/C$. Thus

1. $X \simeq X/A$.
2. We shall show that the map $J : B/(A \cap B) \to X/A, J([b]) = [b]$, is a homeomorphism. Therefore we get $X/A \approx B/(A \cap B) \simeq B$. Hence $X$ is contractible.

Let us now prove that $J$ is a homeomorphism.

Let $p : B \to B/(A \cap B)$ and $q : X \to X/A$ denote the quotients maps. The inclusion $j : B \to X$ has the property $qj = Jp$, thus $J$ is a  continuous map.

Le us write $* = p(A \cap B) \in  B/(A \cap B)$ and $* = q(A) \in X/A$. These points are closed because $p^{-1}(*) = A \cap B$ and $q^{-1}(*) = A$ are closed. The maps $p' : B' = B \setminus (A \cap B) \stackrel{p}{\to} B/(A \cap B) \setminus *$ and $q' : X' = A \setminus A \stackrel{q}{\to}  X/A \setminus *$ are homeomorphisms, thus we may regard $B'$ as an open subspace of $B/(A \cap B)$ such that $B' \cup \{*\} = B$ and $X'$ as an open subspace of $X/A$ such that $X' \cup \{*\} = X$.

We have $X' = (A \cup B) \setminus A = B \setminus A =  B'$, thus $J$ is a bijection. It maps the open subspace $B'$ of $B/(A \cap B)$ homeomorphically onto the open subspace $X'$ of $X/A$. Thus it is an open map at all points of $B'$. It remains to show that $J$ is open at $*$, i.e. that each open neighborhood $U$ of $*$ is mapped onto an open neighborhood of $*$ in $X/A$. Let $U' = U \cap B'$. The set $p^{-1}(U)$ is an open neighborhood of $A \cap B$ in $B$ which has the form $p^{-1}(U) = (A \cap B) \cup U'$. We have $q^{-1}(J(U)) =   A \cup U'$. This set is open in $X$ because $X \setminus (A \cup U')  = (X \setminus A) \setminus U' = X' \setminus U' = B' \setminus U' = B \setminus ((A \cap B) \cup U') = B \setminus p^{-1}(U)$ which is closed in $B$ and thus closed in $X$ (recall that $B$ is a subcomplex of $X$, hence closed in $X$).